# How to put form validation errors in an alert box?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
echo '<p>Username</p>';
echo form_input('username', set_value('username', ''));
echo '<p>Password</p>';
echo form_input('password', set_value('password', ''));
echo '<p>Confirm Password</p>';
echo form_input('password2', ' ');
echo form_submit('submit', 'Create Account');
?>
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error"></div>'); ?>
```

Here is my code and it works fine but the error displays below the form. I want the errors to be on a pop up alert box.

Comment: as a best practice form errors should be displayed form itself. Not as separate `alert`. and there are many answers out there. Try googling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
echo '<p>Username</p>';
echo form_input('username', set_value('username', ''));
echo form_error('username','<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>');
echo '<p>Password</p>';
echo form_input('password', set_value('password', ''));
echo form_error('password','<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>');
echo '<p>Confirm Password</p>';
echo form_input('password2', ' ');
echo form_error('password2','<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>');
echo form_submit('submit', 'Create Account');
?>
```

and remove

```
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error"></div>'); ?>
```

and if you want errors in some kind of sweet alert or any thing
just try the script and edit it as per need use your same code till `form_submit` method and remove `validation_errors` method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if(form_error('username')){ ?>
        alert('<?php echo form_error('password'); ?>');
    <?php } ?>  
    <?php if(form_error('password')){ ?>
        alert('<?php echo form_error('password'); ?>');
    <?php } ?>  
    <?php if(form_error('password2')){ ?>
        alert('<?php echo form_error('password'); ?>');
    <?php } ?>  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
  var username = $("input#username").val();
  var password = $("input#password").val();
  var confirmPassword = $("input#password2").val();
  if(username==""){
      alert('Username cannot be empty');
      return false;
  }
  if(password==""){
      alert('password cannot be empty');
      return false;
  }
  if(confirmPassword==""){
      alert('Confirm password cannot be empty');
      return false;
  }
  if(password != confirmPassword){
      alert("Confrim password doesn't match password");
      return false;
  }
  return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are submitting a form using AJAX, once the validation fails you can alert the message instead of appending it to `'<div class="error"></div>'` this division. Your code in js script may look like this:

```
//Assuming your button ID is submit
$('#submit').click(function (e) {       
  var username = $("input#username").val();
  var password = $("input#password").val();
  if (username == None):
     alert("User name cant be none");
  else if (password == None):
      alert("Password cant be none");
  else:
      //Submit a form after validation is satisfied.
      $.ajax({.......});

});
```

Also there are some JS form validation libraries available, you may use them. Here is the suitable reference for your requirement. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm